# Divrei Yoel Al HaTorah recommendations

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, satmar

I have been looking for a while now, for a newly done typeset for the Divrei Yoel Al HaTorah by Rav Yoel Teitelbaum, the Satmar Rav.

The standard-edition, see [here](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/divrei-yoel-al-hatorah-bamidbar-naso-mahadura-tinyana-800619.html) has the old [Rashi-script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi_script) which I can hardly read.

[image]

Does anyone know if the Divrei Yoel Al HaTorah has been redacted in the newly typeset (block-letters) (non-Rashi script)? Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: I vaguely remember that the Satmar Rebbe was makpid to specifically use Rashi script and not ksav ashuris ...